# XAML Edit & Continue in Visual Studio 2015 (Update 2) does not seem to work

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I cannot get XAML Edit & Continue (WPF) working.

I have Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, so it should work as mentioned here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/04/06/ui-development-made-easier-with-xaml-edit-continue/

However, after any change in XAML source (font size, colors, directly or in resource,...), change is not applied real time.

I am on Windows 7, latest .NET Framework. I must be missing something.

Comment: Same here. Mine won't even let me edit the markup. I can inspect everything just fine. I can change some things by editing in the Live Property Explorer, but I can't edit the xaml.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, I found this in a comment from Dante Gagne (Program Manager @ Microsoft) from the link in your question.
I have VS2015 Professional Update 2 and was wondering what was going on.

> I apologize for the confusion. Edit & Continue is ONLY available in the Visual Studio “15” Preview. The feature is one that we’re still working on, but we didn’t feel was ready for the “RTM” branch yet. That means that Edit & Continue will not work in Visual Studio 2015.
>
> Additionally, if you are working with a Universal Windows Platform
>   project (UWP), you need to be using the Windows Insider build 14295 or
>   later along with the Windows Insider SDK build 14295 or later.
>
> If you’re meeting this criteria and still can’t get it to work, PLEASE
>   get in touch with me and I’ll see if I can help.

His contact details are in the link from your question.
Posted again [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/04/06/ui-development-made-easier-with-xaml-edit-continue/)

**Update 6/23/2016**
Visual Studio 2015 is going to have an Update 3 after all. **However,** As of the current RC, I do not see any plans for xaml edit and continue. See [Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 RC](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs)

**Update 8/12/2016**
As Legends mentioned in his comment VS2015 Update 3 does **NOT** have XAML Edit and Continue. Looks like we're going to have to wait until VS "15" is released. I'll update again if I see Microsoft put a release date out.

**Update 5/10/2017**
VS2017 is out and I believe that is the version where this is supported. Probably no more updates from here on out.

Comment: Oh well, looking forward to when Update 3 comes out!

Comment: Although, I doubt if there'd be an update 3 if the "15" preview is out.

Comment: VS2015 Update 3 has still no support

Comment: @Legends, I saw that... I wonder when vs "15" is supposed to come out. Maybe end of 2016 or early 2017... They did release "Preview 3 for VS '15'" so maybe they're close to being able to pick an RC date.

Comment: Not sure if your comment was ironic :D, but VS 2015 is [RTM](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-vs.aspx) including Update 3..... perhaps it will be available in Update 4 :-)

Comment: Edit and Continue for XAML works in VS 2015 Preview Update 4. I tested it today :-)

Comment: @Grubl3r Are you sure you don't mean VS "15" I don't see any Update 4 preview for VS2015. Do you have a link?

Comment: @matrixugly You are right, it is VS "15" Preview 4, not VS 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Another couple reasons :

- You may be in a Release build. It will let you edit but won't apply changes due to optimizations.
- Your installation may be corrupt. If you don't see XAML listed under Text Editors - that could be the sign of an incomplete install.

See [VS2017 RC1 Installation installation error - Microsoft.PortableLibrary.TargetingPack.Msi failed - No XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774824/vs2017-rc1-installation-installation-error-microsoft-portablelibrary-targeting/41774863#41774863)
   for more details on how I fixed a corrupt install.

[image]

Make sure you're not just being stupid and accidentally reopening the *old* VS2015 after a crash too :-) They look very similar.